# How to correctly define a template class return type of a template function?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, generics

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple. I have a template class `PayloadResult<T>` with a generic payload and in another class a template function which returns an object of such class.

```
class Result
{
public:
    template<class TPayload>
    PayloadResult<TPayload> success(TPayload payload) { return PayloadResult<TPayload>(payload); }
}



template <TPayload>
class PayloadResult
{
private:
    TPayload payload_;

public:
    PayloadResult(TPayload payload)
    {
        payload_ = payload;
    }

    TPayload payload()
    {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

What happens is that the compiler tells me that the `success` function's return type is `No template named 'PayloadResult'`

I changed the return type signature to std::array<TPayload, 1> and it worked. What am I doing wrong? (I am a newbie in C++)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use `PayloadResult` before you declare it.  Swap the order of the classes.

Comment: Also, `template <TPayload>` is not a valid syntax. you want `template <typename TPayload>`

Comment: @Frank right, forgot about that, thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver What if PayloadResult inherits from Result?

Comment: You can forward declare it, but it is weird to have a base class need a derived class to exist to even function.

Comment: @NathanOliver I wanted to use static functions in `Result` in order to initialize generic types with `Result::success(something)` without specifying the type of `something` as a type parameter of `success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/84yg4iVO8) is the corrected example. You have to forward declare the class template PayloadResult<> for using it as the return type as you did in your example. Second you did not have the keyword `typename` or `class` infront of `TPayload`.

```
//forward declare the class template PayloadResult
template <typename TPayload> class PayloadResult;

class Result
{
public:
    template<class TPayload>
    PayloadResult<TPayload> success(TPayload payload) { return PayloadResult<TPayload>(payload); }//now this won't give error because you have forward declared 
};


//added typename
template <typename TPayload>
class PayloadResult
{
private:
    TPayload payload_;

public:
    PayloadResult(TPayload payload)
    {
        payload_ = payload;
    }

    TPayload payload()
    {
        return payload;
    }
};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```